# std::forwarded_list В чём разница между emplace_after и insert_after

Tags: c++, stl, forward-list

я изучаю стандартную библиотеку шаблонов C++ - STL. В std::forwarded_list и в некоторых иных контейнерах имеются методы emplace_after() и insert_after(). Я не совсем понимаю, в чём их основная разница. По имеющейся у меня информации, они оба добавляют объект/значение на место после указанного. Но разумеется, это не единственная причина существования таких функций.

Уточнено: Требуется имплементация обеих методов. Чтобы был наглядный пример, как они работают из под вуали.

Буду благодарен, если поможете в моем нелёгком пути новичка!

Comment: Там всё ясно в первом ответе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659292/what-is-difference-between-insert-and-emplace-for-vector-in-c

Comment: Ладно, спасибо. Может имеются отрывки кода из самой реализации метода или близкий/похожий к самой реализации код? Хотелось бы узнать больше о том как объект "создается на месте" в случае со вторым методом. К тому же, думаю вопрос должен оставаться открытым пока не дан ответ на второй "подвопрос".

Comment: Такое ощущение, что пред созданием вопроса вы не удосужились ни заглянуть в документацию, ни в исходники, где реализованы эти методы.

Comment: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/emplace_after, https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/insert_after.

Comment: Дело в том, что я это как раз таки и видел, однако не понимаю как синтактически реализуется вариант с emplace_after. Ибо там нет ни слова про его имплементацию, говорится лишь об использовании и о принимаемых параметрах. А меня интересуют именно имплементация.

Comment: Вопрос про `front()` надо убрать в отдельный вопрос. С emplace он никак не связан.

Comment: А может стоит просто поменять название вопроса на обсуждение методов STL контейнеров и их имплементация?

Comment: Дело не в заголовке, дело в объемности вопроса. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо за напутствие. В любом случае, ответ про имплементацию еще не получил. (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Visual C++ реализовано так:

```
iterator insert_after(const_iterator _Where, _Ty&& _Val) { // insert _Val after _Where
    return emplace_after(_Where, _STD move(_Val));
}

template <class... _Valty>
iterator emplace_after(const_iterator _Where, _Valty&&... _Val) { // insert element after _Where
    _Insert_after(_Where._Ptr, _STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
    return _Make_iter(_Where._Ptr->_Next);
}

template <class... _Valty>
void _Insert_after(_Nodeptr _Pnode, _Valty&&... _Val) { // insert element after _Where
    _Alloc_construct_ptr<_Alnode> _Newnode(_Getal());
    _Newnode._Allocate(); // throws
    _Alnode_traits::construct(
        _Newnode._Al, _STD addressof(_Newnode._Ptr->_Myval), _STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...); // throws
    _Construct_in_place(_Newnode._Ptr->_Next, _Pnode->_Next);
    _Pnode->_Next = _Newnode._Release();
}

template <class _Ty, class... _Types>
_CONSTEXPR20_DYNALLOC void _Construct_in_place(_Ty& _Obj, _Types&&... _Args) noexcept(
    is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Ty, _Types...>) {
    {
        ::new (_Voidify_iter(_STD addressof(_Obj))) _Ty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
    }
}
```

Т.е. просто вызывается конструктор по месту (placement new).

Но не гарантия, что другой компилятор поступит так же. Не оговорена в стандарте "имплементация".